# Bash, integer variable inside of a string variable

Tags: string, bash

Greetins, I need to do the following:

```
string_a="string_a${int}"
string_b="string_b${int}"
int=1
```

String variables are in a text file, other than file which contains bash script and where variable int is declared. I need that I write `string_a${int}` in a text file, and sed that line from this file so that it becomes a string variable with nested int variable `${int}`. Do you know any nice solution for that? :)

Maybe I try to write codes in both files:

File "string"

```
aaaaaaaaa${i}
```

File "program"

```
#!/bin/bash

int=1
i=1

string=$(sed -n "${int}p" string)

echo ${string}
```

As you can see, I try to sed first line from file "string", but as a result I get aaaaaaaaa${i} instead of aaaaaaaaa1.

Comment: Your question is utterly unclear.

Comment: `String variables are in a text file, other than variable int.` Can you clarify it.

Comment: edited, maybe now it is okay? sorry:)

Comment: like this `echo ${!string_a}`?

Comment: can you tell me what this exclamation changes? I tried to look it up, but I have not found it yet:)

Comment: @user3162968 After `foo=bar` and `bar=5`, `$foo` produces "bar", while `${!foo}` produces 5. The exclamation tells `bash` to use the value of `foo` as the name of the parameter to expand using `$`. It's called indirect parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution. I need to write `eval echo ${string}` instead of echo `${string}`. I hope that it helps someone.

Comment: Can you explain me in a comment how I can write part of a single line in a code block? Four spaces does not work. I would like to write eval echo ${string} inside of a code block.

Comment: Use backticks. (`) - it's the last example in the first line (mini-Markdown) if you click help.

Comment: Never use `eval` when another technique will suffice.